# NULL скрипты

Tags: php, html, mysql

Есть ли разница между NULL скриптом и лицензией. И какие могут быть последствие с NULL скриптом. Например: какой нибудь бан или еще что нибудь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в нуллах часто вирусы и прочий вредный код попадается.

Comment: Спасибо ! Теперь все ясно.

Answer (score 2):

- **На счёт вирусов - не согласен**
- **`ИМХО`** дело обстоит абсолютно также, как и с `крякнутыми` программами:

  > Нету саппорта (Тех. поддержки) и не гарантирована работа скрипта (*чё-нибудь отвалится или какой то функции не будет*).